# No method 'entries_mut' when unarchiving a file with the tar crate?

Tags: rust

I am trying to use the [flate2](https://github.com/alexcrichton/flate2-rs) and [tar](https://github.com/alexcrichton/tar-rs) crates to iterate over the entries of a `.tar.gz` file, but am getting type errors, and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code (and yes, I know I shouldn't use `.unwrap()` everywhere, this is just POC code):

```
extern crate flate2; // version 0.2.11
extern crate tar;    // version 0.3

use std::io::Read;
use std::fs::File;
use flate2::read::GzDecoder;
use tar::Archive;

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("/path/to/tarball.tar.gz").unwrap();
    let mut decompressed = GzDecoder::new(file).unwrap();
    let unarchived = Archive::new(decompressed);
    let entries_iter = unarchived.entries_mut();
}
```

This gives me the error `error: no method named 'entries_mut' found for type 'tar::Archive<flate2::gz::DecoderReader<std::fs::File>>' in the current scope`.

`GzDecoder::new` is returning a `DecoderReader<R>`, which implements `Read` as long as `R` implements `Read`, which `File` does, so that should be fine. `Archive<O>` has different methods depending on what kind of traits `O` implements, but in this case I am trying to use `.entries_mut()`, which only requires `O` to implement `Read`.

Obviously I am missing something here, could someone help shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3):

Oh man, this is tricky. The published documentation and the code *do not match*. In tar version 0.3.2, the method is called `files_mut`:

```
extern crate flate2; // version 0.2.11
extern crate tar;    // version 0.3

use std::fs::File;
use flate2::read::GzDecoder;
use tar::Archive;

fn main() {
    let file = File::open("/path/to/tarball.tar.gz").unwrap();
    let decompressed = GzDecoder::new(file).unwrap();
    let mut unarchived = Archive::new(decompressed);
    let _files_iter = unarchived.files_mut();
}
```

[This commit](https://github.com/alexcrichton/tar-rs/commit/3237ef18d43493347255817c6e7c7b4556183df3) changed the API.

This is a subtle but prevalent problem with self-hosted Rust documentation at the moment (my own crates have the same issue). We build the documentation on every push to the *master* branch, but people use *stable releases*. Sometimes these go out of sync.

The best thing you can do is to run `cargo doc` or `cargo doc --open` on your *local* project. This will build a set of documentation for the crates and versions you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the published documentation of `tar-rs` was for a different version than what was on `crates.io`, so I had to change `.entries_mut` to `.files_mut`, and `let files =` to `let mut files =`.